# ORACLe PROCEDURE - AUTHID allowed only in schema level

Tags: sql, oracle

While trying to create table via procedure, I am facing error like

> Error(73,9): PLS-00157: AUTHID only allowed on schema-level programs

```
PROCEDURE BCKUP 
AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
statusmsg VARCHAR2(400);

BEGIN
    --Backup records
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE schemaname.tabname AS SELECT pgm.* FROM XYZ pgm, IJK prf WHERE prf.col1=pgm.col1 AND prf.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM TAB2)';
    COMMIT;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    statusmsg :='SQL ERRROR CODE ' || SQLCODE|| ' -ERROR- ' ||SQLERRM;
    dbms_output.put_line('ERROR : ' || statusmsg);
END BCKUP;
```

Comment: If I remove AUTHID CURRENT_USER, its compiled success, but while running facing Insufficient privileges Error.

Answer (score 4):

Your procedure seems to part of a package. In a package, you can only set invoker rights (`AUTHID CURRENT_USER`) at the package level. You cannot set it for each individual procedure.

Either move the invoker rights to the package level:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS

    PROCEDURE BCKUP;

    -- more types, procedures and functions

END pkg;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg
AS

    PROCEDURE BCKUP 

    statusmsg VARCHAR2(400);

    BEGIN
        --Backup records
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE schemaname.tabname AS SELECT pgm.* FROM XYZ pgm, IJK prf WHERE prf.col1=pgm.col1 AND prf.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM TAB2)';
        COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        statusmsg :='SQL ERRROR CODE ' || SQLCODE|| ' -ERROR- ' ||SQLERRM;
        dbms_output.put_line('ERROR : ' || statusmsg);
    END BCKUP;

END pkg;
```

Or create a global procedure (i.e. at schema level and not at package level):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BCKUP 
AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
statusmsg VARCHAR2(400);

BEGIN
    --Backup records
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE schemaname.tabname AS SELECT pgm.* FROM XYZ pgm, IJK prf WHERE prf.col1=pgm.col1 AND prf.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM TAB2)';
    COMMIT;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    statusmsg :='SQL ERRROR CODE ' || SQLCODE|| ' -ERROR- ' ||SQLERRM;
    dbms_output.put_line('ERROR : ' || statusmsg);
END BCKUP;
```

Comment: Hi Codo, Yes. I have placed 3 procedures inside a package and set AUTH ID for one procedures.
As you mentioned above, I moved that procedure to separate package and set the access level to Package and its working fine as expected.
Thanks Much :-)