# Oracle's dbms_metadata.get_ddl for type DIRECTORY: invalid input value for parameter SCHEMA

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, dbms-metadata

When I try to call `dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'MYTABLE', 'MYSCHEMA')` either in the pl/sql block or in the package procedure it works fine.

When I try to call `dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'MYTABLE')` (without schema explicitely provided) either in the pl/sql block or in the package procedure it works fine also.

When I try to call `dbms_metadata.get_ddl('DIRECTORY', 'MYDIR')` (without schema explicitely provided) in the pl/sql block it works fine also.

But,

When I try to call `dbms_metadata.get_ddl('DIRECTORY', 'MYDIR', 'MYSCHEMA')` either in the pl/sql block or in the package procedure it raises the error:

```
ORA-31600: invalid input value MYSCHEMA for parameter SCHEMA in function GET_DDL
```

When I try to call `dbms_metadata.get_ddl('DIRECTORY', 'MYDIR')` (without schema explicitely provided) in the package procedure it raises the error:

```
ORA-31603: object "MYDIR" of type DIRECTORY not found in schema "MYSCHEMA"
```

What is the problem?

```
EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE=true
SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE=true
'CREATE ANY DIRECTORY'=true
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Comment: Directory objects don't have schemas so the error message seems reasonable.

Comment: Does it work if you set the package AUTHID to CURRENT_USER? Or if you specify schema SYS in the `get_ddl` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the AUTHID CURRENT_USER clause ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809))

```
create or replace procedure dir_ddl  (dir_name in varchar2) AUTHID CURRENT_USER is
 x clob;
begin
 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('DIRECTORY', dir_name) into x from dual;
 dbms_output.put_line(x);
end dir_ddl;
/

set serveroutput on
exec dir_ddl('PLSHPROF_DIR')
```

And my output is...

```
Procedure DIR_DDL compiled


   CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY "PLSHPROF_DIR" AS '/home/oracle/profiler'


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If I remove the AUTHID clause, I see the same error as you report.

Comment: Trying to compile such as
`function GET_EXTTAB_FPATH (i_table_name in varchar2) return varchar2 AUTHID CURRENT_USER`
I get the:
`Error(72,79): PLS-00157: Only schema-level programs allow AUTHID`

Comment: Setting  `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` at the entire package definition level I got success. See the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113926/oracle-procedure-authid-allowed-only-in-schema-level

Comment: You didn't show us your PLSQL, so I did the most basic example